# How to add filtering to APIView in Django Rest?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, pagination, filtering

I am using APIView consciously. I did pagination but I couldn't figure out how I can add filtering also.Is it possible to use filter_class here, or is there any other way?Here is my code.

**views.py**

```
class userInfoList(APIView):

serializer_class = userInfoSerializer
pagination_class = api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS

def get(self, request, format=None):
    users = userInfo.objects.all()
   
    page = self.paginate_queryset(users)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.serializer_class(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    serializer = self.serializer_class(users, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@property
def paginator(self):
    
    if not hasattr(self, '_paginator'):
        if self.pagination_class is None:
            self._paginator = None
        else:
            self._paginator = self.pagination_class()
    return self._paginator

def paginate_queryset(self, queryset):
    
    if self.paginator is None:
        return None
    return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)

def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    
    assert self.paginator is not None
    return self.paginator.get_paginated_response(data)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from phonenumber_field.serializerfields import PhoneNumberField
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import userInfo

class userInfoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=70)
    phone = PhoneNumberField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return userInfo.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

For pagination I recommend to use limit and offset (it will be sent as query params in request)

Also for filter:
`users = userInfo.objects.all()` - this is your queryset
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

and then you can get filter params and do the next

`users = self.get_queryset().filter(your_filter_params_here)`

here you can use pagination params also
`users = self.get_queryset().filter(your_filter_params_here)[offset: offset + limit]`

btw offset and limit can have some default values in case if it's not sent in request.

Comment: Shouldn't we use filter_queryset() function to see filter's icon on the page?